# Am I understanding JavaScript closures properly?

Tags: javascript, closures

Variables created inside a function, cannot be accessed outside the function.

For example in:

```
function haha()
{
   var a = 5;
}
```

a cannot be accessed outside haha().

And that is where a closure comes in handy:

```
function haha()
{
    var a = 5;
    return function hahainside(){ }
}
newfunction = hahainside();
```

Now, if I call newfunction(), it can access the "a" variable inside the haha().

Am I correct?

I am also wondering why:

```
<script>
    function exclusive()
    {
         d = "Robert, Ryo, Yuri";
         function returnfunction() { alert( d ); }
         return returnfunction();
    }
    ryo = exclusive();
    alert(7);
</script>
```

I am also just wondering why `alert(7);` does not display on my browser.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/XaszL/

Comment: You should declare "d" with `var`

Comment: You cannot access `"a"` once you call `newfunction`. Also, you can just return an Anonymous function inside of your other function, if you want. You don't have to name it. You would have to access `"a"` inside what should be an Anonymous function, before you call `newfunction` to have access to it, but never outside of the scope of `haha`. Maybe you should study Constructors or Objects. I'm not sure what your goal is. Do you understand another programming language?

Comment: @PHPglue I have also learned C, PHP and Java.

Comment: @SnowMagician, please avoid asking two unrelated questions. Second question has nothing to do nor title nor first example.

Comment: `hahainside` is not accessible outside the scope of `haha` (because it is also a variable inside `haha`). I think you want to do `newfunction = haha( );` to get access to the inner function. Then you can do something with `a` to demonstrate that `hahainside` has access to it (Eg: `return function hahainside( ){ alert(a++); }`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need to know:

```
var a = 0;
function haha(){
  a = 5; // when calling haha `a` is accessible to everything below where var is declared
  return function(){
    a = 10; // same as notes above
  }
}
var newfunc = haha(); // `a` will become 5 where var is declared
newfunc(); // now `a` is 10 where var is declared
console.log(a); // works
```

Without having `var a` declared outside of `haha`:

```
function haha(){
  var a = 5; // only available in `haha`
  return function(){
    a = 10; // nearly useless - only scoped to `haha`
  }
}
var newfunc = haha(); // `a` will become 5 where var is declared
newfunc(); // now `a` is 10 where var is declared - can't access `a` where `newfunc` is called
console.log(a); // undefined
```

Maybe you want a Constructor:

```
function haha(arg){
  var whatever = 'something'; // never accessible in a new instance from outside
  this.a = arg;
  this.hahaInside = function(val){
    this.a = val;
  }
}
var newfunc = new haha(20); // `newfunc.a` is now `20`
newfunc.a = 12; // `newfunc.a` is now `12`
newfunc.hahaInside(10); // newfunc.a is now 10
```

As an Object:

```
var haha = {
  a: 5,
  hahaInside: function(val){
    this.a = val;
  }
}
```

No private variables in an Object, and no Constructor arguments. You don't have to call a new instance as an Object, but you may want an new instance. To avoid writing the keyword `this`:

```
if(!Object.create){
  Object.create = function(o){
    function F(){}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F;
  }
}
var newfunc = Object.create(haha); // new 'newfunc` is a new instance of `haha`
```

Real use, no closure:

```
// assuming 3 radio buttons
var ary = ['a', 'b', 'c'], radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('radButs');
var resultVar = '';
for(var i=0,l=radioButtons.length; i<l; i++){
    radioButtons[i].onclick = function(){
      resultVar = ary[i];
  }
}
// resultVar will always be `'c'` because by the time the click Event is called the loop has run all the through and the scope of `i` is global
```

A closure prevents a variable from being scoped higher. Global in this case:

```
// assuming 3 radio buttons
var ary = ['a', 'b', 'c'], radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('radButs');
var resultVar = '';
for(var i=0,l=radioButtons.length; i<l; i++){
  (function(i){
    radioButtons[i].onclick = function(){
      resultVar = ary[i];
    }
  })(i);
}
// now `resultVar` will be `'a'`, `'b'`, or `'c'` respectively, depending on the radio button that you clicked because  `i` becomes separately scoped at each step of the loop even by the time the click Event is called due to user action
```

You can also use use a closure to create a pseudo-static function like this:

```
var count = (function(){
  var c = 0;
  return function(){
    return c++;
  }
})();
```

Now every time you call `count()` it will do just that. The reason this works is because the self-executing function is invoked immediately, scoping `var c` within it, and returning an unexecuted function that increases `c` where it was last scoped.

Comment: Thanks a lot, 

Is my understanding correct that Closures in JavaScript enable the access of variables created inside other functions?   

Or if that is incorrect, then what is the purpose of JavaScript closures in your opinion?

Comment: Real use of closure explained above.

Comment: Adding another real use of closure above.